# Finite Automat Tool

Tags: compiler-construction

Can anyone give some sample program in Lex and Yacc.

Thanks.

Comment: Is Google broken?  http://ds9a.nl/lex-yacc/cvs/lex-yacc-howto.html was the first hit I found.  What did you find when you googled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google "sample program in Lex and Yacc" you will find lots of them.